Angular Service Injection in reusable components
I have a reusable component, ReusableComponent, that needs to use a service that contains an specific function. This service must implement an interface, ServiceAbstraction, to make sure that it contains that function signature. I inject that abstraction in ReusableComponent using a token, so the consumer component has to define it:
export const SERVICE_ABSTRACTION_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ServiceAbstraction>(
  'ServiceAbstraction Token'
);

export interface ServiceAbstraction {
  doSomething(): void;
}

@Injectable()
export class ServiceImplementation implements ServiceAbstraction {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('I do something');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reusable-component',
  template: ``,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ReusableComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(SERVICE_ABSTRACTION_TOKEN)
    private serviceAbstraction: ServiceAbstraction
  ) {
    this.serviceAbstraction.doSomething();
  }
}

Then in any consumer component I can include this reusable component in its template and make use of a concrete service that implements that interface using the providers array of the parent component decorator.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-consumer',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
     <app-reusable-component />
  `,
  imports: [ReusableComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: SERVICE_ABSTRACTION_TOKEN, useClass: ServiceImplementation },
  ],
})
export class ConsumerComponent { }

The problem that I have is that I'd like to be able to have in the parent component different instances of the reusable component that uses different services concretions. Is that possible using angular DI? I know that I could use an input to pass the service to the reusable component, but that would be an antipattern, and I want to use angular architecture and design for DI.
Here you have a stackblitz to tinker with.

code speaks more than a thousand lines, please give a simple example of what you want to achieve as interfaces/component/classes, if possible a working example, which is even more helpful, also explain what is needed!

How are you planning to determine which concrete implementation to use for each instance of the reusable component? It's simple enough if you only have one concrete implementation in each level of the DI tree, but you'll quickly run into trouble if you need two instances at the same level.

You could provide an implementation of that interface that depending on some condition, returns an implementation or another. For instance, if you need to provide a DataService via an injection token, you could create in your providers array a FactoryProvider that depending on some condition creates a FooDataService or a BarDataService. But depending on the condition to test for, this may not be possible. Could you provide some code & specific use case to provide more help?

Thanks for your answers! You are right I should have included some code. I've edited the question to add it. Please, check it out.

yes, @DM, that's exactly the situation, I need to be able to have different concretions for different reusable components that can be shown simultaneously from the same consumer.

@davidlj95, thanks. A factory might be the solution for this, but I don't know how to make angular assign each specific concretion to each of the reusable components in the template

@Pizzicato, gotcha. How can one tell which implementation should be used for a given reusable component instance? Presumably only the parent knows, right? Since it's the one creating more than one implementation of the service? Seems to me like there has to be at least some data passing (even if that's just defining a second injection token pointing at the same interface).

@DM, yep the parent is the one who knows. If it's easier for you we can use the concrete example of an autocomplete component that uses a service with a search method. If we have more than one autocomplete component in a form (parent component), and each autocomplete needs different concretions of the service, e.g., users and orders. This could happen in other forms, with other autocomplete fields with no fixed other, amount of autocompletes, or associated services

and also, yep, there's has to be some data that represents the relationship between the reusable component and the service it has to use

Sorry I took so long to answer, I finally found a way to do this keeping the reusable component ignorant of any injection concretions, you can see it underneath. Thanks for your help.

After lots of research I found a way that meets all my requirements and is fairly simple: As of Angular 14, the createEmbeddedView ViewContainerRef class method allows to add an injector when creating a view that will replace the default injector.
We can create a structural directive that takes the host component View container reference and template reference, and creates the view replacing the injector with whatever provided:
@Directive({
  selector: '[injectService2]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class InjectService2Directive {
  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef, private tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(
      this.tpl,
      {},
      {
        injector: Injector.create({
          providers: [
            {
              provide: SERVICE_ABSTRACTION_TOKEN,
              useClass: ServiceImplementation2,
            },
          ],
        }),
      }
    );
  }
}

And it would be used this way:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <app-reusable-component /> <!-- Default injector will be used (ServiceImplementation) -->
    <app-reusable-component *injectService2 /> <!-- Specified injector will be used (ServiceImplementation2) -->
  `,
  imports: [ReusableComponent, InjectService2Directive],
  providers: [
    { provide: SERVICE_ABSTRACTION_TOKEN, useClass: ServiceImplementation },
  ],
})
export class App {}


I find this solution very elegant since the reusable component is not modified and doesn't take the responsibility of bypassing the Angular DI system. The only thing that I find not so clean is having to create a directive for each service you need to inject, but I guess that it keeps things flexible and allows not to interact with the Angular DI in an explicit way.
Stackblitz with this solution

Note: since this creates a new provider for SERVICE_ABSTRACTION_TOKEN at the component level, this cannot facilitate sharing the service instance between components. Each component will have it's own instance. If you want to share an instance between all components using this directive, inject() the desired instance to the directive and then provide it via useExisting instead of useClass.

I think the closest you can get to relying solely on the DI system is to have an InjectionToken for each concrete implementation. The parent will need to provide each instance of the reusable component with the specific token it should use to retrieve the correct concrete service implementation.
import { Component, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderSearchService, UserSearchService } from './services';
import { ISearchProvider, Order, User } from './models';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from './components/auto-complete.component';

const USER_SEARCH_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ISearchProvider<User>>('user-search-service');

const ORDER_SEARCH_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ISearchProvider<Order>>('order-search-service');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AutoCompleteComponent],
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: USER_SEARCH_SERVICE, 
      useClass: UserSearchService, 
    }, {
      provide: ORDER_SEARCH_SERVICE,
      useClass: OrderSearchService,
    }
  ],
  template: `
    <app-auto-complete [token]="USER_SEARCH_SERVICE" />
    <app-auto-complete [token]="ORDER_SEARCH_SERVICE" />
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent() {}

The reusable component will have to delay injecting the service until the token input is resolved, but that's fairly easy to do if we capture the Injector.
import { inject, InjectionToken, Injector, input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ISearchProvider } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto-complete',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  private readonly injector = inject(Injector);
  readonly token = input.required<InjectionToken<ISearchProvider<T>>>();

  service: ISearchProvider<T> | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service = this.injector.get(this.token());
  }
}

You could use @Input() instead of input.required() if you wanted, but this way throws a compile time error if the token isn't provided which should make ensuring correct usage of the reusable component easier.
Here's a StackBlitz if you want to play around with it.

This is basically injecting the service with more steps. You can simplify it dramatically by just providing the service directly.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderSearchService, UserSearchService } from './services';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from './components/auto-complete.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AutoCompleteComponent],
  template: `
    <app-auto-complete [service]="userService" />
    <app-auto-complete [service]="orderService" />
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent() {
  readonly userService = new UserSearchService();
  readonly orderService = new OrderSearchService();
}

import { input } from '@angular/core';
import { ISearchProvider } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto-complete',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent<T> {
  readonly service = input.required<ISearchProvider<T>>();
}


Both approaches lose type information because working with the search results is working with T[]. I still think extending AutoCompleteComponent<T> is better because you retain type information and you can remove the injection delay since the component now knows which concrete service implementation to inject.
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ISearchProvider, Order, ORDER_SEARCH_SERVICE, User, USER_SEARCH_SERVICE } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auto-complete',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AutoCompleteComponent<T> {
  service: ISearchProvider<T>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-auto-complete',
  standalone: true,
})
export class UserAutoCompleteComponent extends AutoCompleteComponent<User> {
  service = inject(USER_SEARCH_SERVICE);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-auto-complete',
  standalone: true,
})
export class OrderAutoCompleteComponent extends AutoCompleteComponent<Order> {
  service = inject(ORDER_SEARCH_SERVICE);
}

